# Combinations from a set of $5$ items

Tags: combinations

How many combinations will exist from a set of $5$ items; such that $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is one set and $\{2,4,3,5,1\}$ is another set and so on with no duplicates. I am new to this set theory and would like to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item can be chosen in 5 ways. Since we avoid duplicates, the next item can be chosen in 4 ways, and so on. In total, there are $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 120$ combinations.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it will be 25 combinations. Since 5 items in a set arranged in 5 ways.

Comment: What is the formula you used to calculate?

Comment: I use the formula that says that if you want to take $n$ elements without repetitions from a set of $n$ different elements, then you can do this in $n! = n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1$ ways.